# Windows Tablet only for Skype for the elderly

Tags: windows-8, skype

I am thinking of buying a relatively cheap Windows tablet only for Skype, for my parents who are old and not computer-literate. I bought them an ASUS SV1T a few years ago (dedicated Skype video phone) and it worked fine until Microsoft bought Skype and started breaking everything (backwards compatibility with old video codecs, for one).
So I figured the only way to make sure that no matter what this thing will keep working for many years to come, is to have a Windows machine (so, no Linux, Android or other OS).

**But** it has to be dead simple, so no confusing icons/tiles/whatever, preferably just one big Skype icon in the middle and nothing else around it.

So, the question is, can you have a setup like this with a Windows 8.1 tablet?

PS. An added benefit to it being Windows, is that I can install TeamViewer on it and provide remote support easily. Last time I checked there was nothing like it on Android.

Answer (score 1):

I would try putting the Skype shortcut into the startup folder.

[Where is Startup Folder Windows 8](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/where-is-startup-folder-how-to-edit-startup-items-in-windows-8/)

Then have the tablet auto-logon the user account.

[Set Autologin Windows 8](http://www.howtogeek.com/112919/how-to-make-your-windows-8-computer-logon-automatically/)

Then all they should need to know is how to turn it on, and after startup Skype should be waiting for them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but Skype doesn't need to be in the Startup folder to auto-start, that's an option already in Skype. The auto-login is a good point, but I need to bypass the Windows UI (metro) to go directly to Skype.

Comment: [How to Boot Straight to Desktop Windows 8.1](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-boot-directly-to-the-desktop-in-windows-8-1/)  Change that and it will boot straight into desktop.   Just tried whole setup with my Dell Venue 8 Pro Tablet (Win8.1) and it worked fine.  Skype took maybe 30 seconds to get going after startup, but it did work.   I did add the shortcut to startup for Skype.  I had to update my Skype away from the "Metro" version to the Windows for Desktop version.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a Windows 8.1 tablet handy. That's the whole point, I would like to buy one only for my parents (would never use Windows 8.x myself!)

Comment: Then yes it will work.